# Full list of Trove's dungeons/raids types

Tags: trove

I started to play Trove game and got quite confused about what kind of dungeons I can do in order to gather gear. The game changed a lot recent months, so Internet confuses even more.
**Can someone help me to complete the following listing-table?** I want to know all possible type of dungeons where I can find a gear drop. And for each dungeon type: a) how to get in b) what is the loot level c) how much xp you can earn (relatively to other types).

What I saw are:

1. Usual dungeons (towers), which you can complete solo.
   a) You need to find them in [adventure worlds](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Adventure_Worlds).
   b) You can get there a gear appropriate for the world. Shadow level 1 gear is very rare, shadow level 2 - is impossible to get *(is this correct?)*.
   c) Also you earn small amount of XP.
2. Bigger dungeons (castles), which you can complete solo.
   a) Similar to type-1
   b) Similar to type-1
   c) XP amount is bigger.
3. Socialising places, which says "Gather 3 trovians here", which you can not complete solo.
   a) You need to find them in [adventure worlds](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Adventure_Worlds) and gather 3 people near the entry.
   b) Similar to type-1.
   c) 0 xp, I guess.
4. Shadow tower, which you can not complete solo.
   a) You need to use Shadow portal device and spend a [shadow key](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Key) to open the portal.
   b) You can get from Legendary up to Shadow level 1 gear (is this correct?).
   c) For each boss XP amount is approximately the same as with castles.
5. Uber-2/Uber-3/.../Uber-6 shadow towers/arenas.
   I can see such a name when join to someone, but have never found a way to entry them without invite.

So, what does "Uber-X shadow tower" mean and how to get there? How to get a drop with shadow gear level 2+?

Comment: "Gather 3 trovians here" gives same xp as normal small dungeon I believe

Comment: Just today, i completed the Normal difficulty Spike Walker Shadow Tower solo, so maybe edit #4.

Answer (score 1):

Number 4 and 5 are basicly the same thing, when you open portal to Shadow Tower on your own you know what you opened but when someone invites you it usually just says: "Somebody invite you to Shadow dungeon U6" for example or if they are on the final boss it says Shadow pinnacle or something like that. So basically when ppl ninja invite to ST, you usually don't even know which one it is and if it's Hard Mode or not.

Each shadow tower contains 3 dungeons and final room with the boss. Which dungeons are before each boss is every week rotated.

**Shadow Tower list(from easiest to hardest):**

1. Spike Walker
2. Weeping Prophet
3. ** Pinata
4. Daughter of the Moon (you need lunar key to open this one)

Each can be opened on normal/hard mode.
For completing 1-3 on normal + hard mode once(you can do it more times a week but you get this award only once a week) each week you get titan souls(1 for normal SW, 2 for normal WP and 3 for the rest). For completing DOTM you get 1 Lunar soul per each mode.

So in total you can gain 15 titan souls - for which you can buy chests at ST shop and 2 lunar souls every week(for which you can get various things at ST shop too).

I will update my answer later when I can login.